# GDB: Attempt to dereference generic pointer

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb

How can I make GDB do extra dereferences in a printing function like
`x/s`?

When I try explicit dereferences in `x/` I get the error "Attempt to
dereference a generic pointer". Using `x/` multiple times works, since
each use includes an implicit dereference, but this is annoying since
I have to copy and paste each intermediate result.

## Example

Consider the very useful C program, `example.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("argv[0] = %s\n", argv[0]);
}
```

If I build it and load it into GDB, I see that `argv` is stored at
`0xc(%ebp)`, since a double dererence of that is passed as the second
argument to `printf` (i.e. in `0x4(%esp)`) on line 26:

```
$ gcc -o example example.c
$ gdb example

(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x080483e4 <+0>:   push   %ebp
   0x080483e5 <+1>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080483e7 <+3>:   and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x080483ea <+6>:   sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x080483ed <+9>:   mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x080483f0 <+12>:  mov    (%eax),%edx
   0x080483f2 <+14>:  mov    $0x80484e0,%eax
   0x080483f7 <+19>:  mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
   0x080483fb <+23>:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x080483fe <+26>:  call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x08048403 <+31>:  leave  
   0x08048404 <+32>:  ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

I break at `printf` and run the program with arguments `first` and
`second`:

```
(gdb) break *main + 26
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483fe

(gdb) run first second
Starting program: /var/tmp/SO-attempt-to-dereference-generic-pointer/example first second
```

I attempt to print `argv[0]` in GDB, but I get the "generic pointer"
error:

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x080483e5 in main ()
(gdb) x/s **(0xc + $ebp)
Attempt to dereference a generic pointer.
```

However, by using 'x/xw' to manually dereference a few times, I'm
eventually able to print `argv[0]` (and `argv[1]`):

```
(gdb) x/xw 0xc + $ebp
0xbfffeba4: 0xbfffec34
(gdb) x/xw 0xbfffec34
0xbfffec34: 0xbfffedc8
(gdb) x/s 0xbfffedc8
0xbfffedc8:  "/var/tmp/SO-attempt-to-dereference-generic-pointer/example"

(gdb) x/xw 0xbfffec34 + 4
0xbfffec38: 0xbfffee03
(gdb) x/s 0xbfffee03
0xbfffee03:  "first"
(gdb)
```

But this is annoying and indirect (as pointer programming is wont to be?)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The solution is to cast the pointers before dereferencing them.

For example, picking up where we left off above:

```
(gdb) x/s **((char ***) (0xc + $ebp))
0xbfffedc8:  "/var/tmp/SO-attempt-to-dereference-generic-pointer/example"
(gdb) x/s *(*((char ***) (0xc + $ebp)) + 1)
0xbfffee03:  "first"
(gdb) x/s *(*((char ***) (0xc + $ebp)) + 2)
0xbfffee09:  "second"
```

Note that the stack address `0xc + $ebp` is itself a pointer to the
contents of that stack location, and so we need `char ***` and not
`char **`.

Comment: Why cannot this process be automated by GDB? I _know_ that I'm working with a pointer, otherwise I wouldn't have asked to dereference. Clearly if I ask to dereference again, then the result of the first dereference must be a pointer...

Comment: @Radon Rosborough: There is always more than one option. Maybe you want the address. Maybe you want a different cast. - Of course gdb could try it with the most likely option by default. But that's a uncertain way. C is the wrong language for that.

Comment: In general GDB _does_ automate the process of figuring out the type -- when you're using it normally as a source-level debugger on a binary with symbols where it can figure out the type of what you're working with from the debug information and the context. GDB's handling of expressions is very mechanistic and typed-language-oriented, which is somewhat inconvenient for the very basics like this at the machine level, but avoids having things go sideways real fast when you start dealing with pointer arithmetic or overloaded *.

Comment: What should I do for `x/i`?